BLDC Thermofan PWM Controller design recommendations
This circuit is intended to drive small automotive cooling fans (~70W)
The gate drive IC is failing when starting from a stall and pops instantly. If current is limited on startup to around 5 A, however, the circuit was operating well at 20-50 kHz. Unfortunately, it would fail after a few 10 s of cycles when starting from stall. The IC ends up shorting the PWM input pin to GND leaving the circuit inoperable.
I'm seeking advice to the best design approach moving forward to drive the fans reliably, I understand thermo-fan PWM controllers exist, but their temperature ranges do not meet our requirements.
I believe it would be better to drive the fans using this buck converter style circuit.
If this is the case, any recommendation on whether to use a P-CH FET or bootstrap an N-CH to be able to switch on the high side? What would be the simplest solution here to address the switching and gate drive?
Otherwise, aside from protecting the driver outputs with Schottky diodes, are there any fundamental or important flaws that can be seen in the current design?
Some notes
Power requirements: 13.8 V nominal running voltage (from DC-DC in vehicle) @ full speed ~5.2 A or ~70 W.
Fans have a resistance of 1.2 ohms, giving around 12 A in-rush current requirement at startup.
I also believe my choice of gate resistors was under-rated?
According to the gate-driver's datasheet, 10 ohms is double the minimum output resistance for safe operation given Ciss = 2250 pF. I fear that the small low power resistors may not be suitable and potentially are lowering their resistance under operation?

